# Latest Chromecast (21.0.1) produces crash from Android 12: ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException

Tags: android, chromecast, android-12

Precondition

1. `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` 31.
2. `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:21.0.1` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:21.0.1`

Crash

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.ondemandkorea.android/com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService
       at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)
       at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:50)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3345)
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2432)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2421)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2404)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2346)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startService(IActivityManager.java:6897)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1926)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1892)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:796)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.internal.zzp.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@20.1.0:33)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.internal.zzp.onStatusUpdated(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@20.1.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.zzbo.zzm(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@20.1.0:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.internal.zzap.zzaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast@@20.1.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.internal.zzap.zzQ(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast@@20.1.0:65)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.RemoteMediaClient.onMessageReceived(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@20.1.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.zzbn.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast@@20.1.0:4)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8582)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:563)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

I have seen similar SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70044393/fatal-android-12-exception-startforegroundservice-not-allowed-due-to-mallows) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69604951/getting-android-app-foregroundservicestartnotallowedexception-in-android-12-sdk), but those were caused by starting some foreground service manually.

As you can see in the stack trace, I'm not really starting any services myself. In fact, I don't even have `startForegroundService()` call in my codebase.
It looks like Chromecast is doing the service implementation, but I don't know where to start to debug this. Someone reported an [issue](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/115) in the Chromecast github, but no one has replied.

If anyone experienced similar issue, please help me debug this (or reproduce the issue).

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, that issue is unlikely to accomplish much. That is not a Chromecast GitHub repo. It is a repo for a sample app. A hopefully-relevant issue is [the one on the Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206864385), where [somebody from Hulu suggests a workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206864385#comment9).

Comment: sigh, I was able to reproduce the issue using the same step from that thread. I guess I'll just have to wait till the fix is out. Thank you!

Comment: As of today, the SDK is still not updated to fix the issue

Comment: They released a new update (21.1.0) on 8th August and it will fix the crash: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes

Comment: @EhsanHeidari that took a good amount of time for them :'). Thank you!