# How to use activity recognition Exemptions to start foregroundService from background?

Tags: android

Android 12 adds restrictions to launch ForegroundService from background, and the document mentions several Exemptions too. One of them is “Your app receives an event that's related to geofencing or activity recognition transition”.
I cannot find any document to talk it in detail.  Here are my questions.

1. do I have to launch my ForegroundService immediately after I get this event? How long is the window?
2. do I have to call startForegroundService(...) in the same thread as that the event from?
3. do I need to pass some parameters from the event to launch my ForegroundService?

My device is Pixel 3a with Android 12

Comment: I tried to launch a ForegroundService in another thread after an Activity Transition event, but I still get the Exception in Android 12. Anything wrong?

Comment: Similarly I’m trying to launch a foreground service as a result of a BLE scan result (another permitted exception) and getting the same error. 

I’m thinking of rolling back to A11 and waiting for 13 instead.

Comment: I am facing the same issue after the geofence event. As per the official doc, they provide an exemption for events that are related to geofencing or activity recognition transition. Last month when I tested the case of the exemption it was working fine but not now .

Comment: What solution you ended up with?